# Change the color of the remaining area after using border-bottom-right-radius in CSS

Tags: css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Hi guys, how do I change the area in the remaining area (on the right side with the white color) to blue and left side of the remaining area (on the left side  with the white color) to black using css? Anyone can help me would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```css
.upper-container {
  position: relative;
  /* Establishes a new stacking context */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Places the .upper-container in front of other elements */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5rem;
}

.lower-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Set lower z-index */
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper-container"></div>
<div class="lower-container"></div>
```

This is how I made the curve and I have no idea how to change the color for the remaining area outside the curve

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean exactly, but maybe this will help, if not tell me.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.upper-container,.lower-container {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.inner-cont1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5rem;
}

.inner-cont2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 5rem;
}

.out-container1{
    background-color: blue;
}
.out-container2{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="out-container1">
    <div class="inner-cont1"></div>
</div>
<div class="out-container2">
    <div class="inner-cont2"></div>
</div>
```